# K functional of $L^{1,\infty}$ and $L^\infty$ real interpolation

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, interpolation

I want to know where can I find how to compute, given a function $f$ and $t>0$
$$K(t,f;L^{1,\infty};L^\infty)$$
where $L^{1,\infty}=\sup_{t>0}t f^*(t)$
and $K$ is the Petree K-functional associated to the real interpolation method.